# python variables have the same id

Tags: python, variables

I'm new to Python , i have the question here. I know the scope thing that whenever a variable is called , python looks into the current scope to see if it exists , if not then go out to the outer scope. Here's my question , i have a global variable x and two local variables as the same name in different functions. But the output shows that one local variable has the same id as the global one. I assume  which confused me. If anyone could explain it to me i really appreciate!

```
 x = 10

def variablesTest():
    x = 10
    print(id(x))

def variablesTest2():
    x = 20
    print(id(x))

variablesTest()
variablesTest2()
print(id(x))
```

//output
1643250448
1643250768
1643250448

Comment: `id()` gives the identity of the *object*, that is the integer object with the value 10 or the integer object with the value 20.  In python, names like `x` are only *references* to objects, not the objects themselves.

Comment: Thanks man , you made it really clear.